# Events not triggering after appended element

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Hello**

So I'm trying to make dynamically added rows and when you enter numbers into those rows it should calculate some stuff, the first element that's not appended works fine but the rest isn't getting triggered.

I've tried multiple solutions using `$(document).on('keyup change', 'element')` and some more.
What I'm trying to achieve is that the calculations should work on every appended row as well.

[jsFiddle added](https://jsfiddle.net/twdbmusn/)

Comment: You need to add event listeners to the newly added inputs.

Comment: Your click handler sets the Custom Data Attribute `data-target` to empty string ("").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have few issues in your code.

First of all you do not have the attribute like *data-target*, *row_margin*, *data-sum* set in any of the newly appended element that you are using to find the specific element.

You also have to use ***delegation approach*** to attach the event handler which will allow you to fire/raise the event on the elements that are appended dynamically. You can pass `this` to the function so that you can refer elements only specific to the current *table*.

```
$('body').on('input', 'div.list div.list_row table', function(){
  CalculateMargin(this);
});
```

You also do not loop through using `.each()`.

Try the following way:

```js
var offer_rows_i = 2;

$('body').on('input', 'div.list div.list_row table', function(){
  CalculateMargin(this);
});

$("div.section_button[data-action='new-offer-row']").click(function(){
  $("div.list").append(`<div class="container list_row mt3 w-100 zoomInDown animated fast" data-temp=${offer_rows_i}><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" align="left" width="9.5%"><input type="text" data-target="row_article" autocomplete="none" /></td>
      <td valign="top" align="left" width="17%"><textarea data-target="row_text"></textarea></td>
      <td valign="top" align="left" width="10%"><input type="text" data-target="row_quantity" autocomplete="none" value="1" class="numbers" /></td>
      <td valign="top" align="left" width="12.5%"><input type="text" data-target="row_price_in" autocomplete="none" value="0,00" /></td>
      <td valign="top" align="left" width="12.5%"><input type="text" data-target="row_price_out" autocomplete="none" value="0,00" /></td>
      <td valign="top" align="left" width="12.5%"><input type="text" data-target="row_discount" autocomplete="none" class="numbers" /></td>
      <td valign="top" align="left" width="12.5%"><input type="text" data-target="row_margin" data-margin="0" data-percentage="0" autocomplete="none" value="0,00 (0%)" readonly="readonly" /></td>
      <td valign="top" align="left" width="10%"><input type="text" data-target="row_sum" data-sum="0" autocomplete="none" value="0,00" readonly="readonly" /></td>
      <td valign="top" align="center" width="3.5%"><i class="fas fa-times" data-action="delete-row"></i></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table></div>`);

  offer_rows_i = offer_rows_i + 1;
});
      
function CalculateMargin(row){
  var bruttoCalc = 0;
  var summaCalc = 0;
  //console.log("changing => " + $(row).data("temp"));
  var quantity = $(row).find("input[data-target='row_quantity']").val();
  var priceIn = $(row).find("input[data-target='row_price_in']").val();
  var priceOut = $(row).find("input[data-target='row_price_out']").val();
  var discount = $(row).find("input[data-target='row_discount']").val();

  // Row calculations
  var tbSumTotal = 0;
  var priceInSum = (quantity*priceIn);
  var priceOutSum = (quantity*priceOut);
  var discountSum = ((priceOutSum/100)*discount);
  var totalSum = (priceOutSum-discountSum);

  // TB calculations
  var tbDiscount = ((quantity*priceOut)*(discount/100));
  var tbSum = ((quantity*priceOut)-tbDiscount);
  var tbTotal = (tbSum - (quantity*priceIn));
  if(!tbTotal || !isFinite(tbTotal)){
    tbTotal = 0;
  }
  tbSumTotal = (tbSumTotal + (tbSum-(quantity*priceIn)));

  // Percentage calculations
  var marginRawPercentage = (tbTotal/(quantity*priceOut));
  var marginPercentage = Math.round(parseFloat(tbTotal/tbSum)*100);
  if(!marginPercentage || !isFinite(marginPercentage)){
    marginPercentage = 0;
  }

  // Show results
  $(row).find("input[data-target='row_margin']").val(parseFloat(tbSum-(quantity*priceIn)).toFixed(2).replace(".", ",") + " ("+marginPercentage+"%)");
  $(row).find("input[data-target='row_sum']").val(parseFloat(priceOutSum-discountSum).toFixed(2).replace(".", ","));
  
}
```

```css
div.section_button{
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: auto;
  float: right;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  margin: 0 0 0 7px;
  border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #808080;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 9pt;
  font-weight: 500;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
div.section_button:hover, div.section_button:focus{
  outline: none;
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  border: 1px solid #ececec;
}
div.section_button.colored{
  background-color: #305286;
  border: 1px solid #305286;
  color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
div.section_button.colored:hover, div.section_button.colored:focus{
  outline: none;
  background-color: #203b64;
  border: 1px solid #203b64;
}
table{
  margin: 15px 0 0 0;
}
div.list_row > table{
  margin: 0;
}
table thead th{
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 9pt;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #404040;
  padding: 20px 10px 16px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
  border-left: 0;
  border-right: 0;
}
table thead th:first-child{
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  border-left: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
}
table thead th:last-child{
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  border-right: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
}
table thead tr th input[type="checkbox"]{
  margin: 2px 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div.list_row > table tbody td{
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 9pt;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #808080;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
div.list_row > table tbody tr:hover td, div.list_row > table tbody tr:focus td{
  background-color: rgba(247, 247, 247, 0.5);
}
div.list_row > table tbody tr td input[type="checkbox"]{
  margin: 2px 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div.list_row > table tbody tr:last-child td:first-child{
  border-radius: 0 0 0 3px;
}
div.list_row > table tbody tr:last-child td:last-child{
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 0;
}
div.list_row > table tbody tr td input[type="text"]{
  background-color: transparent;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: 44px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 9pt;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #606060;
}
div.list_row > table tbody tr td:nth-child(7) input[type="text"]{
  background-color: rgba(247, 247, 247, 0.5);
  border-left: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
  border-right: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
}
div.list_row > table tbody tr td:nth-child(8) input[type="text"]{
  background-color: rgba(247, 247, 247, 0.5);
  border-left: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
}
div.list_row > table tbody tr td textarea{
  background-color: transparent;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: 18px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 16px 10px 8px 10px;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 9pt;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #606060;
  resize: none;
}
div.list_row > table tbody tr td i.fas{
  margin: 16px 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
div.list_row > table tbody tr td i.fas:hover{
  color: #404040;
}
section#economy div.offer_calc table{
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
  padding: 0 0 15px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #ececec;
}
section#economy div.offer_calc table:last-child{
  border-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
section#economy div.offer_calc table tr td{
  padding: 2px 0;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 9pt;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #808080;
}
section#economy div.offer_calc table tr td:first-child{
  font-weight: 600;
}
section#economy div.offer_calc table:nth-child(3n) tr:last-child td{
  padding: 8px 0;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section_button colored" data-action="new-offer-row"><i class="fas fa-equals"></i> New row</div>
<br /><br />
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th valign="top" align="left" width="9.5%">Artikel</th>
      <th valign="top" align="left" width="17%">Free text</th>
      <th valign="top" align="left" width="10%">Quantity</th>
      <th valign="top" align="left" width="12.5%">In price</th>
      <th valign="top" align="left" width="12.5%">Out price</th>
      <th valign="top" align="left" width="12.5%">Discount %</th>
      <th valign="top" align="left" width="12.5%">TB</th>
      <th valign="top" align="left" width="10%">Sum</th>
      <th valign="top" align="center" width="3.5%"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
<div class="list">
<div class="container list_row mt3 w-100" data-temp="1">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" align="left" width="9.5%"><input type="text" data-target="row_article" autocomplete="none" /></td>
      <td valign="top" align="left" width="17%"><textarea data-target="row_text"></textarea></td>
      <td valign="top" align="left" width="10%"><input type="text" data-target="row_quantity" autocomplete="none" value="1" class="numbers" /></td>
      <td valign="top" align="left" width="12.5%"><input type="text" data-target="row_price_in" autocomplete="none" value="0,00" /></td>
      <td valign="top" align="left" width="12.5%"><input type="text" data-target="row_price_out" autocomplete="none" value="0,00" /></td>
      <td valign="top" align="left" width="12.5%"><input type="text" data-target="row_discount" autocomplete="none" class="numbers" /></td>
      <td valign="top" align="left" width="12.5%"><input type="text" data-target="row_margin" data-margin="0" data-percentage="0" autocomplete="none" value="0,00 (0%)" readonly="readonly" /></td>
      <td valign="top" align="left" width="10%"><input type="text" data-target="row_sum" data-sum="0" autocomplete="none" value="0,00" readonly="readonly" /></td>
      <td valign="top" align="center" width="3.5%"><i class="fas fa-times" data-action="delete-row"></i></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you asked, that every row you added should be working as well as your first line, which in technical term is that every dynamically added row should also register and trigger the same event as the first fixed row, is rather a simple question. However, your real objective of this table is a bit complicated, in fact this may be a code sample useful to me too:

1. In first line, by completing at least Quantity, In price, Out price (or maybe you required to input the first 2 columns first), the table should automatically compute and output TB and Sum.
2. By clicking "New row" button, a new row with same column as the first line should be added into the table
3. In the new added line, by completing at least Quantity, In price, Out price, the table should automatically compute and output TB and Sum.

Down to your own code now:

> Your first row almost works fine, only when some of the case
>   (input order), your TB and Sum may result **NaN**, but this is just a
>   small bug to fix.
>
> The second line you added by clicking the button did not work.

The reason that this happened is because the first row is written in HTML, and when JS `$("div.list div.list_row table").on(...)` is loaded, it has detected the only row in HTML. And this makes the first row element registered to `keyup` and `change` event that calls to `CalculateMargin()` function.
The second row is added dynamically, and **it is not yet register to any event** at this point. Therefore, it will not apply `CalculateMargin()` function.

So in order to make the second row work, all you need to do is to register the row with `$("div.list div.list_row table").on(...)`. This is the simple part.

> **Debugging method:** 
>   If you have Firefox or Chrome to inspect your
>   code/page, by comparing the two rows of elements, you will find under
>   `Event Listeners`, only row one has got `change` and `keyup` event
>   listed, and row two has nothing in it.

Try to replace part of your code:

```
$("div.list div.list_row table").on('keyup change', function(){
   // test if the event is triggered
   alert ("altered");
   //CalculateMargin();
});
```

And you will see that by adding a new row, your new row won't pop up this alert message like the first one.

So in your next part of your code:

```
$("div.section_button[data-action='new-offer-row']").click(function(){
    $("div.list").append('<div class="container list_row mt3 w-100 zoomInDown animated fast" data-temp="'+offer_rows_i+'"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%"><tbody><tr><td valign="top" align="left" width="9.5%"><input type="text" data-target="" autocomplete="none"></td><td valign="top" align="left" width="17%"><textarea data-target=""></textarea></td><td valign="top" align="left" width="10%"><input type="text" data-target="" autocomplete="none" value="1"></td><td valign="top" align="left" width="12.5%"><input type="text" data-target="" autocomplete="none" value="0,00"></td><td valign="top" align="left" width="12.5%"><input type="text" data-target="" autocomplete="none" value="0,00"></td><td valign="top" align="left" width="12.5%"><input type="text" data-target="" autocomplete="none"></td><td valign="top" align="left" width="12.5%"><input type="text" data-target="" autocomplete="none" value="0,00 (0%)" readonly="readonly"></td><td valign="top" align="left" width="10%"><input type="text" data-target="" autocomplete="none" value="0,00" readonly="readonly"></td><td valign="top" align="center" width="3.5%"><i class="fas fa-times" data-action="delete-row"></i></td></tr></tbody></table></div>');

    offer_rows_i = offer_rows_i + 1;

    // register and enable event for new row
    $("div.list div.list_row table").on('keyup change', function(){
        // test if the event is triggered
        alert ("altered");
        //CalculateMargin();
    });
});
```

Now both your line applies to your event， with new problem:
**Your event **triggered multiple times**. Besides your two events `change` and `keyup` that causes double trigger, every time you click on "New row" button all the row elements will register to event by code `$("div.list div.list_row table").on(...)`, and it will **add to** the element event list instead of replacing previous event.

To solve this you will have to clear all pre-registered event and re-register.

Here is the code: [1. Add new row event trigger test](https://jsfiddle.net/deadlyblinder/k5e7xdbq/10/)

Now you could uncomment your `CalculateMargin()` to replace the test message `alert ("altered")`.

However, the second line still compute as expected. This is because (like @Qonvex620 @Rob Moll) said, when code processing to `var quantity = _this.find("input[data-target='row_quantity']").val();` and so on, the data fetched results `undefined`.

That is because the code could not find `row_quantity` here. Check your code in `append`, you will see `<td valign="top" align="left" width="10%"><input type="text" data-target="" autocomplete="none" value="1"></td>` where **data-target=""** means there is no value (`row_quantity`) for it. This applies to following elements:

- row_article
- row_text
- row_quantity
- row_price_in
- row_price_out
- row_discount
- row_margin
- row_sum

Here is the final code that works for you: [2. Enable all row cell event](https://jsfiddle.net/deadlyblinder/k5e7xdbq/9/)

Comment: Appreciate the explaining through out the code and what to think about, I had a 14 hour coding session while writing the append function, simple forgot to add the targets for the Custom Data Attributes

Answer (score 0):

In the html for your first row which is plain-old html you have this:

```
<td valign="top" align="left" width="9.5%"><input type="text" data-target="row_article" autocomplete="none" /></td>
```

Notice the Custom Data Attribute named `data-target` is assigned a value of `"row_article"`.

However, in your dynamic code the CDA named `data-target` is assigned a value of "".

```
<td valign="top" align="left" width="9.5%"><input type="text" data-target="" autocomplete="none"></td>
```

You just need to add the corresponding value in your dynamic code to all of the `td`'s that have this `data-target` CDA.

Answer (score 0):

Provide a value for your `data-target` since you are getting input's value through their data-target attached to them.

In you first row it will definitely work because you had provided value on their data-target. like this

```
<input type="text" data-target="row_price_in" autocomplete="none" value="0,00">
...
...
```

However in your newly added input, you just put like this without providing any data-target value

```
<input type="text" data-target="" autocomplete="none" value="0,00>
```